# Rails Validation for a has_one and belongs to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, associations

I am currently working on a project where I have a Warranty Attached to a Device via a has_one association (Device has one warranty, and warranty belong to device). Everything works fine except for the fact that it was suggested to me by one of my colleagues to add a presence validation on the device_warranty_ends attribute of device_warranty to make sure at least this field was populated if a device had a warranty.

However the problem is that now, you can't create a device without a warranty and that is obviously not a real life situation since a device can naturally exist without a warranty. So, my question is, how can I validate device_warranty_ends only when a device_warranty is being attached to a device.

In other words, creating a Device should not care about warranties, except when someone actually does attach a warranty to a device (by filling in the fields), then and only then I should check for device_warranty_ends presence: true .

Thanks.

Here is my current validation code:

```
class DeviceWarranty < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :device
validates :warranty_ends_at, presence: true
end

class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :device_warranty
```

Comment: Share your current validation code.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your use of has_one to assign Warranty to all Device objects.  You can certainly create a "Warranty" object that is used in the program to represent that the device does not have a Warranty.

If your program requires all Warranties to belong to a Device, you can just run the check for ends in Warranty so only the Warranties that end are allowed to be created.

Comment: How would I do this:  "You can certainly create a "Warranty" object that is used in the program to represent that the device does not have a Warranty." Sounds like a viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a custom validation in the `Device` model, which checks if it has a warranty.

Such as:

```
class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :warranty_must_exist

  def warranty_must_exist
    errors.add(:id, 'warranty must exist') if self.warranty.blank?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my issue using, reject if:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :device_warranty, :reject_if => proc { |attrs| attrs.all? { |k, v| v.blank?}}, :allow_destroy => true
```

basically, it rejects the validation if the the fields are blank, and if they are not it checks that device_warranty_ends is filled.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help me.